# Obtener parametros w_0 w_1

Tags: python, theano

Necesito obtener los parámetros `w_0` y `w_1` con Theano.

Este es el enunciado:

Crea un conjunto de datos utilizando el siguiente código:

```
trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
trY = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
for i in range(len(trY)):
trY[i] = math.log(1 + 0.5 * abs(trX[i])) + trX[i] / 3 + np.random.randn() * 0.033
```

Ahora, utiliza Theano para obtener los parámetros `w_0` y `w_1` del siguiente modelo:

```
y = log (1+ wo|x|)+ w1|x|
```

Utilizando los datos generados anteriormente.

Este es mi código:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


trX = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
trY = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)

for i in range(len(trY)):
    trY[i]=math.log(1+0.5 * abs(trX[i]))+trX[i]/3 + np.random.rand() * 0.033
```

Comment: Estoy un poco perdido con theano y necesito una ayuda

Comment: Hola Eduardo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberías dar algo más de contexto a la pregunta, explicar más claramente cuál es el problema, qué son `w_0` y `w_1`, etc. Mírate [ask]. Para añadir más información, no uses los comentarios, edita la pregunta usando el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/262934/edit) que hay debajo de ella y añade en ella todo lo necesario. Un saludo.

Comment: Perdón, tienes ra´zon, edito el enunciado. Gracias.

Comment: Falta un detalle: cuál es el problema con el código que pones en la pregunta?